# Отсортировать массив по частоте

Tags: php

Дана строка с целыми числами от 1 до 500, разделенных запятыми. Числа могут повторяться.

Требуется взять 10 самых часто встречающихся и поместить в массив отсортированный по убыванию частоты.

Не придумал ничего лучше, кроме как посчитать частоту в отдельном массиве, в котором число является ключем, а частота - значением. Отсортировать `arsort()`. 
Топ-10 пришлось в отдельном цикле выделять, т.к. array_slice не сохраняет ключи.

Может есть какая-нибудь встроенная функция для таких вещей или можно как-то проще сделать?

ps: Код страшный, показывать стыдно.

**UPDATE:**

Огромное спасибо, в комментарияx помогли.

```
$arr = array_count_values(explode(',', $str));
arsort($arr);
$res = array_slice($arr, 0, 10, TRUE);
```

Comment: `array_count_values(explode())`

Comment: @Akina спасибо. Вместо `split()` у меня `explode()`. Это нормально? Есть ли какой-то аналог `array_slice()`, чтобы сохранял ключи?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov `array_slice` умеет сохранять ключи массива, если передать четвертым параметром значение `TRUE` (FALSE по умолчанию).

Comment: @AntonMironov отлично. сработало. спасибо.